# If $E$ is a vector space, is there an established terminology for functions $f:E\times E\to\mathbb R$ whose values $f(x,y)$ only depend on $y-x$?

Tags: terminology, symmetric-functions

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-vector space and $f:E\times E\to\mathbb R$ with $$f(x,y):=g(y-x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E.$$

> Is there an established terminology for such a function $f$?

(I'm aware of a similar terminology in the case of normed $\mathbb R$-vector spaces $X$: A function $h:X\to\mathbb R$ is called *radial* if $h(x)=r(\left\|x\right\|_X)$ for some $r:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$.)

Comment: All such function would be the 'doubly translation invariant functions' (made up name). Namely, you would have $f(x,y) = f(x-h,y-h) = \tau^hf(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in E$ and $h = (h,h)\in E^2$, where $\tau^h$ is the translation operator $(\tau^h \phi)(x,y) = \phi(x-h,y-h)$. Conversely if $\tau^h f = f$ for all $h$ then set $g(x) = f(0,x)$, from which it follows that $f(x,y) = \tau^x f (x,y) = g(y-x)$ for all $x,y\in E$.

Comment: Are $f$ or $g$ linear?